# Detect ordered pair in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am using a numpy array to hold a list of ordered pairs (representing grid coordinates). The algorithm I am writing needs to check if a newly generated ordered pair is already in this array. Below is a schematic of the code:

```
cluster=np.array([[x1,y1]])
cluster=np.append(cluster,[[x2,y2]],axis=0)
cluster=np.append...etc.

new_spin=np.array([[x,y]])

if new_spin in cluster==False:
    do something
```

The problem with this current code is that it gives false positives. If x or y appear in the cluster, then `new_spin in cluster` evaluates as true. At first I thought a simple fix would be to ask if `x` and `y` appear in `cluster`, but this would not ensure that they appear as an ordered pair. To make sure they appear as an ordered pair I'd have to find the indices where `x` and `y` appear in `cluster` and compare them, which seems very clunky and inelegant, and I'm certain there must be a better solution out there. However, I have not been able to work it out myself.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Its a bit annoying because of a small bug that is related to it in numpy <1.7., but if you query the same set many times, you should use sorting, or maybe hack something with `scipy.spatial.cKDTree` if the current bugs in numpy are too annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's work through an example:

```
In [7]: import numpy as np
In [8]: cluster = np.random.randint(10, size = (5,2))
In [9]: cluster
Out[9]: 
array([[9, 7],
       [7, 2],
       [8, 9],
       [1, 3],
       [3, 4]])

In [10]: new_spin = np.array([[1,2]])

In [11]: new_spin == cluster
Out[11]: 
array([[False, False],
       [False,  True],
       [False, False],
       [ True, False],
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

`new_spin == cluster` is a numpy array of dtype `bool`. It is True where the value in `cluster` equals the corresponding value in `new_spin`.

For `new_spin` to be "in" `cluster`, a **row** of the above boolean array must all be True. We can find such rows by calling the `all(axis = 1)` method:

```
In [12]: (new_spin == cluster).all(axis = 1)
Out[12]: array([False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

So `new_spin` is "in" `cluster`, if `any` of the rows is all True:

```
In [13]: 
In [14]: (new_spin == cluster).all(axis = 1).any()
Out[14]: False
```

---

By the way, `np.append` is a very slow operation -- slower than Python `list.append`. Chances are, you will get much better performance if you avoid `np.append`. If `cluster` is not too large, you may be better off making cluster a Python list of lists -- at least until you are done appending items. Then, if needed, convert `cluster` to a numpy array with `cluster = np.array(cluster)`.

Comment: I did end up using a list of lists, which can be queried using a simple `(x,y) in cluster` statement without issue (and because one of my friends pointed out that lists should be faster to use than arrays, and I didn't really need it to be an array - I'm just used to working with them as a data type).

I like your answer for using arrays, and it's good to know that any and all can accept axes.

Comment: @DylanB from the built-in datatypes, `set` is most likely preferable to a list though, since its `in` is much more efficient.